# Entity Framework Include statements loading unexpected extra data

Tags: entity-framework

Here's a snippet of my repository code:

```
public IQueryable<Task> GetTasks()
{
    return Entities.Tasks.Include("Categories")
                            .Include("Categories.Documents")
                            .Include("Categories.Documents.User");
}
```

In my model, User objects have a Documents navigation property which, you'll note, I'm not asking for here. Yet the object tree that results from this statement includes all the Documents collection on each User and, furthermore, all the Users on each of those Documents and so on, all the way down the rabbit hole.

Why am I getting all these unasked for properties, and is there anything I can do to stop them? I only actually need a single property on each User object, but AFAIK you can't "Include" or "Load" individual properties. I'm using DB first so, again AFAIK, there's no straightforward way of making this a one-way relationship (for my purposes only Document.User matters,not User.Document).

Comment: If lazy loading is disabled with `bd.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`, will change something?

Comment: Load options defined somewhere?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik Thanks for looking. Lazy Loading is disabled in the edmx properties. I added the manual config change you suggested too, just in case, but it makes no difference. Still getting all the unasked for entities.